# jsp update multiple rows from table

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, servlets

I'm writing a website using JSP and Servlet that require updating multiple record in a table in JSP into the database MSSQL. Suppose I have a table like this:

Post.jsp

```
<form method="POST" action="PostServlet?action=update">
      <table border="1">
          <tr>
              <th>Post ID</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
          <c:forEach var="p" items="${requestScope.list}">
            <tr>
                <td>${p.id}</td>
                <td>${p.title}</td>
                <td>${p.date}</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="slStatus">
                       <option value="approve" selected="true">Approve</option>
                       <option value="unapprove">Unaprove</option>
                     </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </c:forEach>
          <tr><button type="submit" value="Update"></button>
      </table>
```

Suppose I pick and change the Status in several rows. What should I put in my Servlet so that it update all the changed value in the table into the database? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sending the primary key value also with the status as like:

```
<form method="POST" action="PostServlet?action=update">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Post ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="p" items="${requestScope.list}">
            <tr>
                <td>${p.id}</td>
                <td>${p.title}</td>
                <td>${p.date}</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="slStatus">
                        <option value="approve" selected="true">Approve</option>
                        <option value="unapprove">Unaprove</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" name="postId" value="${p.id}"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </c:forEach>
         <tr><button type="submit" value="Update"></button>
    </table>
```

Now in your servlet you can find and update the status based on the primary key value.
**Note : *postId* and *slStatus* parameters would be having equal length array values (at servlet). and at the same index they will represent the respective values of one object(of Entity class i.e. representing DB table).**

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that not what I'm looking for. I want to know how to update all the rows in the table when click on the update button. What code should I put in the servlet to update all the change status? Suppose I have a Update method call `updatePost` to update a Post

Comment: you will get postId and slStatus parameters values from the request (will get array of string). Now find the row in the table by postid in loop (array of values got from request) and update the row with the status value at same index in the loop .